# Click handler for setting the active color and shape button in a drawing program

Tags: java, event-handling

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source.equals(jbColor1))
            color = getBlue();
        else if (source.equals(jbColor2))
            color = getRed();
        else if (source.equals(jbColor3))
            color = getGreen();
        else if (source.equals(jbColor4))
            color = getBlack();
        else if (source.equals(jbColor5))
            color = getYellow();
        else if (source.equals(jbColor6))
            color = getPink();
        else if (source.equals(btnRectangle)) {
            isSelectedReactangle = true;
            isSelectedCircle = false;
            isSelectedLine = false;
            btnRectangle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));
            btnLine.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(defaultbtnLable));
            btnCircle.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(defaultbtnLable));
            count = 0;
        } else if (source.equals(btnCircle)) {
            isSelectedReactangle = false;
            isSelectedCircle = true;
            isSelectedLine = false;
            btnCircle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));
            btnLine.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(defaultbtnLable));
            btnRectangle.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(defaultbtnLable));
            count = 0;
        } else if (source.equals(btnLine)) {
            isSelectedReactangle = false;
            isSelectedCircle = false;
            isSelectedLine = true;
            btnLine.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));
            btnRectangle.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(defaultbtnLable));
            btnCircle.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(defaultbtnLable));
            count = 0;
        } else if (source.equals(btnClear)) {
            btnLine.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(defaultbtnLable));
            btnRectangle.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(defaultbtnLable));
            btnCircle.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(defaultbtnLable));
            panelContent.repaint();
        }
}
```

I have some code but i would avoid if else statement. 
for example this snippet code is repeating few times.

```
btnLine.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));
btnRectangle.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(defaultbtnLable));
btnCircle.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(defaultbtnLable));
```

Some tips and tricks how to avoid if condition so many times

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your original title was too generic to be appropriate for this site. I had to take a guess at what this code does. If you could provide more context about your goals, we could provide better advice. See [ask].

Comment: Can you show me those `getPink`, `getBlack` etc methods?

Comment: @Simon Forsberg for example private Color getGreen() {
  return Color.GREEN;
 } 
Other methods are analogous

Comment: @WalterWhite With methods that simple, why have them as methods at all?

Comment: @SimonForsberg I'm using this code in few place and I think this should be good if i use method but You are right this method are so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you have one `actionPerformed()` method for multiple UI elements instead of creating each button with its individual `Action` instance? Like:

```
Action clearAction = new AbstractAction("Clear") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btnLine.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(defaultbtnLable));
            btnRectangle.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(defaultbtnLable));
            btnCircle.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(defaultbtnLable));
            panelContent.repaint();
        }
}
btnClear = new JButton(clearAction);
```

[Disclaimer: may contain typos, didn't check it in an IDE]

Then the Action is a first-class object, can be bound to multiple UI elements (e.g. a button and a main menu item) and contains both the name (plus an icon if you like) and the implementation.

And if the `Actions` have common elements, maybe it's worth having them inherit from a common base `Action` class.

Comment: Yes, common base `Action` classes are very useful. In fact, most often they don't need to *inherit* from those, but can instead be an *instance* of those by passing the right arguments to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to put the code into a function:

```
void setSettings(YourClass object, boolean isSelectedReactangle, boolean isSelectedCircle, boolean isSelectedLine) {
    object.isSelectedReactangle = false;
    object.isSelectedCircle = true;
    object.isSelectedLine = false;
    btnCircle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));
    btnLine.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(defaultbtnLable));
    btnRectangle.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(defaultbtnLable));
    count = 0;
}
```

You would still probably have to use the if/else, as switch statements can only switch on limited types of objects.

Also, Reactangle should probably be Rectangle.